# ItemTouchHelper does not update items when swiping

Tags: android, itemtouchhelper

I have a `RecyclerView` that uses an `ItemTouchHelper` to allow users to swipe each item.  Everything works fine on the initial load but if the items in the `RecyclerView` are updated (via a search feature) the items in the `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` never change and are always the initial items, even though items displayed in the app have changed.

```
public class ListActivity {
    private RecyclerView mItemsList;
    private String mQuery;
    private static int SEARCH_RESULTS_CODE = 131;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mItemsList = findViewById(R.id.list);
        SetContent();
    }

    private void SetContent()
    {
        List<String> items = GetItems(mQuery); //returns different items depending on query string.  Initial load is all items.

        ItemsAdapter adapter = new ItemsAdapter(items);
        mItemsList.setAdapter(adapter);

        final ItemTouchHelper itemTouchhelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new CustomSwipeController(items));
        itemTouchhelper.attachToRecyclerView(mItemsList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SEARCH_RESULTS_CODE) {
                mQuery = data.getData().toString();
                SetContent();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(final MenuItem menuItem) {
        final int itemId = menuItem.getItemId();

        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.menu_drawer_episode_list_search:
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class), SEARCH_RESULTS_CODE);
                break;
        }
    }
}


public class CustomSwipeController extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

    private List<String> mItems;

    public CustomSwipeController(List<String> items)
    {
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        String item = mItems.get(position);  //these items are always the initial load of items, even though the items displayed in the app have changed
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
After some debugging, if I've found the items don't change in `onSwiped`.  If I put a breakpoint in the constructor of CustomSwipeController the items are changed but not when swiping on an item.

UPDATE 2:
I've figured out a workaround.  Instead of refreshing the items in `onActivityResult`, I'm starting a new activity, like this:

```
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
```

It's not ideal but it works.

Comment: When you say they never change, do you mean visually the items are not showing properly? I'm making sure I understand the question correctly.

Comment: Visually the items change, it's in the code where they don't change.  It's almost as if the items from the initial load are cached when `onSwiped` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Well, while I'm not sure I entirely have the whole picture here or understand fully what is happening I can offer a pointer to try and remedy your issue.

When setting up a `RecyclerView`, it is best to hold a reference to your custom adapter and update the data through a public method. This way you aren't recreating your adapter and assigning it every time a new set of data comes through. Something like this on your adapter:

```
public void updateData(List<CustomData> listCustomData) {
    this.listCustomData = listCustomData;
    notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

The next step is to deal with your `ItemTouchHelper`. Even though it's older, it might be helpful to look at this as a [simple implementation](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf) example to see if you are doing anything incorrectly.

Best of luck.

Comment: Actually, I do have a method in my adapter like that, I just didn't think to use it for displaying the search results.  Maybe refreshing the recylcerview that was will fix the data in `onSwiped`.